# How to install the GMP extension for elastic beanstalk on Amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have already added two files for the amazon elastic but configuration but it does not work.

.elasticbeanstalk\eb.config

```
files:
"/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
mode: "000644"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
extension=php_gmp.dll
```

.elasticbeanstalk\software.config

```
packages:
yum:
php7.0-gmp: []
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue. The solution is to install php70-gmp and to add the extension to the ini:

**In any.config:**

```
container_commands:
  01_install_gmp:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: |
      sudo yum install -y php70-gmp
files:
  /etc/php.d/z_project.ini:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=gmp.so
```

Comment: did this actually work for you? I tried it but it crashes the server.

Answer (score 0):

After several days. this works for me,

1. create  .ebextensions folder
2. create a new config file instal_gmp.config
3. Add the following: be consistent with your indentation

commands:

```
    command1:
            command: sudo yum install -y php73-gmp
    command2:
            command: sudo restart httpd
```